# How to set xcode debugger working directory with CMake

Tags: xcode, cmake

I searched for an equivalent of [VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY.html) for xcode in cmake documentation, but I couldn't find one. If it indeed doesn't exist, how I can use existing cmake functions to achieve setting the working directory to what I want while running the xcode debugger for my c++ application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone is interested, I figured it out. It's

```
set_target_properties(<your-target> PROPERTIES 
                      XCODE_GENERATE_SCHEME TRUE
                      XCODE_SCHEME_WORKING_DIRECTORY <desired-directory>)
```